# Salesforce SOQL To Get Case Owner In One Hit

Tags: salesforce, soql

Using Salesforce SOQL I can get the Owner's Id using the following:

```
SELECT Case.OwnerId 
FROM Case 
WHERE Case.CaseNumber = '00001234'
```

I can then get the User details for the User who owns the case in this query:

```
SELECT User.Id, User.Name, User.Custom_Field__c 
FROM User 
WHERE User.Id = '001A0000001abc1DEF'
```

But I can't get it to work in a single statement, I think this is because Owner != User, even though the owner is in fact a user in this case. I have tried:

```
SELECT Owner.Custom_Field__c
FROM Case 
WHERE Case.CaseNumber = '00001234'
```

But I get an error that the Custom_Field__c is not a valid field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a semi-join in SOQL. I tested it out, and it still works even though Owner is polymorphic:

```
SELECT Custom_Field__c 
FROM User 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT OwnerId 
             FROM Case
             WHERE Case.CaseNumber = '00001234')
```

Comment: Yeah, but you can't get the case fields from that query.

Comment: @altaiojok - what API version do you need to use to do this?

Comment: Nice answer - I didn't think it was possible, but this totally works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Owner on Case is a polymorphic relationship, it can be one of multiple different types. When that happens then using SOQL-R you can only select a subset of fields that are common to the types being pointed to (these are all exposed on a pseudo entity called "Name"), so you won't be able query the custom fields on User. You'd have to do a query on Case, then collect up the set of Owners and make a query to User and/or Group to the get more detailed information.

Comment: Now this semi-joins are available, this can be done from the User object on a list of case owners

Comment: It still can't be done on Attachment's polymorphic relationship (Parent) "Entity 'attachment' is not supported for semi join inner selects"